# Stained concrete

Tags: concrete, porch, new-home

I went to change out my doormat (those coconut-husk fiber ones) and there was a stain and it's sticky. The stain is not size of the doormat, it looks like someone spilled a drink in front of our door. I thought it was dirt/mud(it's rained alot and our yard was a mud pit for months till the builder finally installed grass) and went to scrubbing it with water and alil dawn dish soap. Stain is still there, I think the sticky is gone(it's still drying). Do these doormats cause this?  Is the concrete defective?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it's highly unlikely that the sticky stain was caused by your fiber mat or defective concrete.
Without knowing the cause, it's difficult to recommend a specific solution. You should talk to your builder. One of his helpers may have spilled something and didn't clean it well.
However, there are numerous concrete cleaners on the market, one of which will almost certainly remove the stain. It's always best to start with the mildest which you've already done with soap and water.
Next I would try a concrete driveway cleaner that you can buy at any home store in your area. Even the mild ones can be caustic so follow the directions carefully using protective gloves and eyewear as recommended.
If that doen't remove it you may have to go stronger with a muriatic acid solution. Be careful of the strength you're buying. They range from a weak muriatic acid solution to full strength. Again follow directions carefully. I've used full strength to remove varnish stains from a concrete entry but a weaker solution should do the job for you.